# Hiding rows older than 60 days

Tags: microsoft-excel

This isn't as simple as it sounds (at least not to me). This is my issue:

I have a single sheet spreadsheet that is sorted first by a custom table (In PROCESS, WIN, FUTURE) (col E) and then by the dates (col J) (old to new), leaving a second set of rows that need to be sorted by dates (new to old) and then anything older than 60 days needs to be hidden.

I am just learning about macros and don't have all the nuances learned. I need something that will look at the column with text (BID, NO BID, LOSS), and then sort by date and hide the dates older than 60 days.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the version of the code that you've got so far. It'll be much easier to help when people can see how far you've come / what you're currently needing help with.

Comment: Also posting a sample of your spreadsheet data (i.e. the column headers and one or two rows of data) would be helpful. You can change the actual data if privacy is a concern.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & add a new TAG 'VBA' since this issue needs a macro !

Answer (score 0):

*Your issue can be solved, using VBA macro:*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
      If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
      End If

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Hide Selected Rows", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each xCell In xRg
        If xCell.Value < Now - 60 Then
            xCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- From **D**eveloper TAB hit **D**esign Mode then left to it is **I**nsert, click it.
- From Active X category select **C**ommand button.

[image]

- Draw Command button on sheet.
- **R**ight click command button & from Poped up menu hit **P**roperties.
- Find **C**aption and change it to **H**ide Rows, return to the Sheet.
- Now, **D**ouble click Command button to open VB editor.
- **C**opy & **P**aste shown code from `Row no 2 to 18`.

---

```
     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Copy code here

    End Sub
```

---

- **S**ave Workbook as **M**acro Enabled (.xlsm)  & return to the Sheet.
- Deactivate the **D**esign Mode.
- Finally **D**ouble click the Command button.
- Using the **I**nput Box, select required Rows & finish with **O**k,

### [image]

[image]

---

[image]

---

*In Addition you may use this code to unhide, those hidden rows.*

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
     Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
   End Sub
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Like I said, I am new at this. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help you @Linda,, read carefully & follow the instruction, this will works without any problem.